# How to convert date format from "28-03-18 09:11:34.000000000 PM" to "MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS" in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to convert the date for one reporting project where I've got  stuck with below:

```
select 
UPDATED_DT, to_CHAR(UPDATED_DT,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE(to_CHAR(UPDATED_DT,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from COMPANY;
```

Result:

```
28-03-18 09:11:34.000000000 PM          03-28-2018 21:11:34           28-03-2018 21:11:34
```

If you observe i am getting correct format with TO_CHAR, however i want the date in date data type. how can i achieve "MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"?

Comment: The date data type does not have a human-readable format, it has an internal representation. Your client/IDE/application/reporting tool will usually convert that to a formatted string (e.g. using your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting) for display; `to_char()` will do the same. If this is a reporting project then you probably need to tell your reporting tool how to format the date value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set the format you want

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';